# Convert DateTime.Parse() format to date and time in jqgrid

Tags: c#, javascript, sql-server, jqgrid

I am using `jqGrid 4.4.1` and `C#.net`.  I am converting a date field from `sqlserver` using `DateTime.Parse()`.  It is sent to the `jqgrid` in this format:

`1/5/2012 4:05:00 PM`

I want it displayed in that same format, but my `formatoptions` must not be correct because this value:

`4/18/2007 11:21:00 AM`

is being displayed like this

`28/11/2010`

Here is my `formatoptions` setting:

`{ "srcformat": "n/j/Y g:i:s A", "newformat": "n/j/Y  g:i:s A" }`

I have other date fields that correctly display `4/18/2010` as `4/18/2010` using:

`{ "srcformat": "m/d/Y", "newformat": "m/d/Y" }`

I am guessing it is an issue with the `srcformat` but none of the many combinations I have tried are working.

With no leading zeros on day, month, or hour and AM/PM with a 12 hour clock, what is the correct `srcformat` I should be using?

As a date works just fine with this method, I prefer convert formats in `jqgrid` to avoid special parsing when time is included with date.

**Edit:**

If I don't try to format the field as a date, it correctly displays the date, but I am unable to sort by that field as it does not get sorted as a date.

Comment: Can you format the string as you like in advance and send it to the jqGrid in string format?

Comment: The date has to be converted to a `json` string in order for `jqgrid` to use it.  I can change the format prior to changing it to a string, but I don't want to break all the other dates in the grid.  If DateTime.Parse() doesn't create the right format, what format should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it wasn't an issue with the format of the strings, it was an issue with how I was passing that format.  Rather than passing the `formatoptions` as an object, I was passing it as a string.  Once I made that change, my formatting works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
{ "srcformat" : "m/d/Y h:i:s A", "newformat" : "n/j/Y g:i:s A" }
```

Comment: I already tried that combination.  Also, since my months are without leading zeros, I cannot use `m` (same with `d` and `h`).